# Sitecore SIM Installation permission error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-instance-manager

I am trying to install **SIM version 13 rev 1404021** using Administrative priveleges

When i click on **Grant** button it give me error that " you dont have neccessary permission set".

Also i have given full permission to *Network Service,IUSR, IIS_USR and network* to the folder

> C:\Inetpub\wwwroot

Kindly let me know whate else permission need to be given inorder to run sitecore instance manager succesfully.

Comment: In my case, it seemed that the user credentials for the SQL user weren't correct, so I made sure the user was a sysadmin and the connection string was correct, then this issue was fixed. So it looks like just a bug with the UI in SIM (for me anyway)

Comment: Mark's comment applied to me too - despite the cryptic error message, the real error was because my SQL connection string wasn't correct and the specified user did not have permissions.

Comment: Just to add that if the SQL server is on different machine, you will get the same error also. I think they are planning to fully support remote SQL server in version 2.0

Comment: As Mark mentioned, check the conn string user is a sysadmin. That was my problem!

Answer (score 15):

It may be caused by bug in SIM that doesn't get actual SQL Server user account (LocalService or custom) and thinks that it is always NetworkService. So work around is to switch your SQL Server service from using LocalService or custom account to NetworkService.

[image: SQL Server Properties]

Comment: Do this first (the installer prompts you to as well now I noticed) and then look at Mark's comment on the OP's question :)

Answer (score 10):

Same context with Alen's answer, but in windows 10.

Use '**Local System account**' and tick the '**Allow service to interact with desktop**'. 
Then, restart the service.

At this point, you don't need to reopen the SIM installation window. You can just click the **Grant** button and it would work.

[image]

Comment: Had similar issue on Windows 8, above steps helped to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for me the issue was that the database user didn't have the `dbcreator` role so the wizard couldn't create databases in SQL Server.

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Expand Security > Logins
3. Double-click on the user to open the properties dialog
4. In Server Roles, check the `dbcreator` role
5. Press OK and enjoy

Source: http://sitecoreblog.patrickperrone.com/2015/04/a-simple-error.html

Answer (score 1):

When you downloaded the SIM zip file from Marketplace, did you click "Properties" on the zip file and click the "Unblock" button before unzipping and running it?

[image: Properties dialog]

I've found in the past that forgetting this step can be the cause of odd security related errors with applications.

Comment: I have tried your above step, but still i am getting the same Error. But the same file i have run on different machine giving Network Service permission it got installed succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across a similar issue I had, but for me root issue was that the wwwroot folder was on a VM/Parallels and that folder was marked "compress" and "archive"

unset that for wwwroot and child items, and then SIM proceeded correctly.