# Unable to install Sitecore 8.0 using SIM 1.4

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-instance-manager

I see this error when installing Sitecore 8.0 using SIM 1.3 or 1.4. Also set permissions for NETWORK SERVICE manually, to wwwroot folder.

How to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: What account is MSSQLSERVER configured to run under? Make sure it is NETWORK SERVICE account: http://i.imgur.com/ZHuHX4s.png

Comment: The SQL server I want to connect to is up and running with many other DBs. Is it mandate that Sitecore SQL servers should always be 'Network Service'. Need to check with IT if they can change. But is there any other way?

Comment: No, it is not a requirement for Sitecore although it does seem to be a requirement for SIM. You don't _have to_ use SIM, use the exe installer or manually install using the zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here worked perfect for me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxMGdbz-eEs

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.

To open SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the Search charm, under Apps, type:

```
SQLServerManager13.msc for [SQL Server 2016] or
SQLServerManager12.msc for [SQL Server 2014] or
SQLServerManager11.msc for [SQL Server 2012] or
SQLServerManager10.msc for [SQL Server 2008], and then press Enter.
```

2. In the left pane, select "SQL Server Services".
3. In the right pane, select "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)". Right click > Properties. Check "Built-in account" and in the dropdown select "Network service".

Answer (score 4):

Probable you have a SQL Server 2012 or higher.

Unlike previous versions SQL Server 2012 by default uses virtual user account called NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER which is not supported by SIM.

It is a known SIM issue see
[Known Issue - SQL Server 2012 default user account is not supported](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Instance-Manager/wiki/KnownIssue-SqlServerDefaultAccount)
on the Sitecore Instance Manager (SIM) Wiki.

To use SIM change the SQL Server account to use NETWORK SERVICE", change the user account associated with the Windows service named SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) to `NETWORK SERVICE`

See [Sitecore SIM Installation permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533060/sitecore-sim-installation-permission-error/23625765#answer-38549587)

Comment: On the way to get this done. But will changing the SQL Server's user account will it affect any of the exisiting DB's. They are used by other non sitecore apps. Thank you.

Comment: @JanBluemink What steps must be taken to _"change the SQL Server account to `NETWORK SERVICE`"_?

Comment: @JanBluemink I figured it out.  To _"change the SQL Server account to use `NETWORK SERVICE`_", change the user account associated with the Windows service named `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` to `NETWORK SERVICE`.  I recommend editing your answer with explicit instructions on how to do this.  Do so, and you'll have my vote.